# Translating a MySQL data/query-set into the equivalent Cassandra representation

Tags: mysql, nosql, cassandra

Consider a 500 million row MySQL table with the following table structure ...

```
CREATE TABLE foo_objects (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  foo_string varchar(32),
  metadata_string varchar(128),
  lookup_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (foo_string),
  KEY (lookup_id),
);
```

... which is being queried using only the following two queries ...

```
# lookup by unique string key, maximum of one row returned
SELECT * FROM foo_objects WHERE foo_string = ?;
# lookup by numeric lookup key, may return multiple rows
SELECT * FROM foo_objects WHERE lookup_id = ?;
```

Given those queries, how would you represent the given data-set using Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options:

(1) is sort of traditional: have one CF (columnfamily) with your foo objects, one row per foo, one column per field.  then create two index CFs, where the row key in one is the string values, and the row key in the other is lookup_id.  Columns in the index rows are foo ids.  So you do a GET on the index CF, then a MULTIGET on the ids returned.

Note that if you can make id the same as lookup_id then you have one less index to maintain.

High-level clients like Digg's lazyboy (http://github.com/digg/lazyboy) will automate maintaining the index CFs for you.  Cassandra itself does not do this automatically (yet).

(2) is like (1), but you duplicate the entire foo objects into subcolumns of the index rows (that is, the index top-level columns are supercolumns).  If you're not actually querying by the foo id itself, you don't need to store it in its own CF at all.